# Can I enter the US with refugee travel document?

Tags: usa, paperwork, refugees

I would like to travel to the US for holidays. I have a refugee passport issued by The Netherlands, and I want to go to the US.

I am not a permanent resident of The Netherlands. I have temporary permission to stay for 5 years on my asylum ID and travel document.

Can I just book my ticket and go to the US, or do I need to request a visa online or should i go to the US Embassy in The Netherland?

Answer (score 5):

You will need a visa.  Visas are not issued at the US embassy in The Hague.  Instead, you must apply [at the US consulate general in Amsterdam](https://nl.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/).

> The Consulate General in Amsterdam is responsible for providing visa services to those seeking to enter the United States for a temporary period and for those wishing to take up indefinite or permanent residence in the United States. There is no visa section at the U.S. Embassy in The Hague.

Before you go to the consulate, however, you will need to [fill out an online application](https://ceac.state.gov/GenNIV/Default.aspx) and [register online for your appointment](https://ais.usvisa-info.com/en-nl/niv/).